# FFmpeg. avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264) return false

Tags: c++, qt, encoding, ffmpeg, x264

**The problem:** I can not connect the h264 codec for encoding and decoding of frames.

---

**Description:**

I downloaded from here ffmpeg library https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/, version dev.

Connect it to your project QT:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <libavcodec\avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat\avformat.h>
    #include <libavformat\avio.h>
    #include <libswscale\swscale.h>
    #include <libavutil\mem.h>
}
    
#pragma comment (lib, "avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "avformat.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "swscale.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "avutil.lib")
```

Next prescribe `av_register_all();` to include all codecs.

Next, call the function: `avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264)`, returns false.

In the ReadMe file, the library said that it was collected with --enable-libx264 and --enable-gpl compile the keys including h264 codec that is supposed to be.

If the call: `avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO)`, it returns an object AVCodec, as it should.

I use the MinGW compiler. OC Windows 7.

How can I resolve or work around the problem? Compile the library itself has not yet obtained. I understand you to connect sources and "poking" them, that too is meaningless.

---

** Once again, I will describe my problem: **

I need to encode the codec h264 (can VP9) individual frames in one program, and then decode them in another program. You can use other libraries. The language C ++. It is necessary to use interframe compression codec, rather than simply pressed apart frames.

Sorry for my english.

Ideas. Advice. Suggestions.